# directorio de página en php no se ve

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente url de mi página:
https://www.mipaginawebaqui.es/clases-ingles-online/
Que no se puede ver no aparece nada y me aparece este mensaje:
Multiple Choices
The document name you requested (/clases-ingles-online/.php) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.

Available documents:

```
/clases-ingles-online/. (common basename)
/clases-ingles-online/.. (common basename)
```

Sin embargo si la url le añado el archivo https://www.mipaginawebaqui.es/clases-ingles-online/index.php
Si se puede ver correctamente.
¿NO se si por favor podrías indicarme cual es error que hace que no se pueda visualizar https://www.mipaginawebaqui.es/clases-ingles-online

En el archivo .htaccess
Tengo esto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^miweb.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.miweb.es/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

redirect 301 /sitemap.html https://www.miwersreew.es/
```

redirect 301 /ror.xml https://www.miwerbsss.es/

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola. ¿Estás escribiendo la URL así: `/clases-ingles-online/.php`? Parecería que hay reglas `.htaccess` que están quitando el nombre a los archivos con extensión `.php` ¿?

Comment: He puesto el codigo que esta .htaccess , quizas este mal he hecho un redirect 301 para evitar la duplicidad de la home y algun otro redirect

Comment: Pues eso, creo que esta regla `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` quita el nombre a los archivos con extensión `.php`, prueba a comentarla,  poniendo `#` delante: `# RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` y guarda el `.htaccess` y prueba de nuevo. Para URLs amigables, ese no es el camino.

Comment: He dejado solo esta parte del archivo .htaccess 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.web.es/$1 [L,R=301,NC]  y esta funcionando bien. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Comment: Podrias explicar el problema y tu solucion en la respuesta?

Comment: Si he modificado el archivo .htaccess,  he dejado el código que he puesto en la anterior repuesta y lo he subido al servidor. No sabía como solucionarlo y con la modificación todo funciona ok. Mi agradecimiento a la respuesta de A. Cedano que me ha solucionado el problema.